# Where should I instantiate my WebDriver instance when looping?

Tags: python, selenium

I am iterating a list of links for screen scraping.  The pages have JavaScript so I use Selenium.  I have a defined a function to get the source for each page.

1. Should I instantiate the `WebDriver` inside that function, which will happen once per loop?
2. Or should I instantiate outside the function and pass the `WebDriver` in?
3. Or assign the `WebDriver` to a variable that will be visible from inside the function, without explicitly passing it?

Comment: Your original question was not appropriate for SO. You were asking about libraries, in general. What you should or can do is going to vary from library to library and depending on what you are trying to do. In its original form you question was both too broad and opinion-based, which would have resulted in closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instantiation of `WebDriver` launches a new browser, which is a very costly operation, so option 1 is not what you want to do.

I would also not do option 3 because it is not good coding practice to depend on global variables when it can easily be avoided.

This leaves you option 2: instantiate `WebDriver` once and pass the instance to your function(s).

Comment: Thanks for the edit Louis.  So option 2 would look something like this:
```
def func(url,d):
  d.get(url)
  src = d.page_source
  # do stuff
  return(result)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for i in list:
  func(i, driver)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Louis.  So option 2 would look something like this:

    def func(url,d):
      d.get(url)
      src = d.page_source
      # do stuff
      return(result)
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    for i in list:
      func(i, driver)

Comment: Hard to read python code in a comment but it looks okay to me. If I read this well you instantiate before the loop and then the loop calls `func` and passes the driver as the 2nd argument. If I read this right, then what you suggest is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  Thanks for the direction on this.

Comment: By the way, using `page_source` may not work the way you want. One of [my answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27636548/1906307) deals with the issue.